# How to install "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" driver in Alpine Linux Docker Container

Tags: linux, docker, ms-access, odbc, pyodbc

## Script to find all drivers

I created a script to find all 'pyodbc' drivers:

```py
import pyodbc

print([x for x in pyodbc.drivers()])
```

## The problem

In my host computer (Windows with drivers installed), when I'm run i get all x64 drivers:

```sh
> ['SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server', 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)', 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)', 'Microsoft Access dBASE Driver (*.dbf, *.ndx, *.mdx)', 'Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)']
```

But, when I use Docker

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

# Add dependencies
RUN apk upgrade
RUN apk add --no-cache curl gcc g++ unixodbc-dev
RUN ln -s /usr/include/locale.h /usr/include/xlocale.h

WORKDIR /app

# Install Python dependencies
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Run script
COPY find_drivers.py find_drivers.py
CMD [ "python3", "find_drivers.py" ]
```

Drivers are not found:

```sh
> []
```

## References

- [Install ODBC driver in Alpine Linux Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888064/install-odbc-driver-in-alpine-linux-docker-container)

What the best way to install "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" in this Docker image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What the best way to install "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" in this [Alpine Linux] Docker image?

You can't. Microsoft only provides "Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)" for the Windows platform (unlike their ODBC driver for SQL Server which is available for Windows, Linux, and Mac).

Some alternatives are discussed here:

[Working with an Access database in Python on non-Windows platform (Linux or Mac)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25596737/2144390)